# KDE Plasma splash screen freezing on fresh install of Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, windows, kde, dual-boot, plasma5

I am trying to install Arch Linux alongside Windows 10 (for a dual boot system).

Every time I try to install Arch Linux with KDE Plasma, I can never make it to the desktop.  Sometimes, it will make it to the desktop after a fresh install, but after a few boots it will not make it past the display manager, then after that it will not even start the display manager.

I have tried to install Arch countless times, and each time I have:

1. Deleted the partitions in windows to erase root, swap, home
2. Used `diskpart` in cmd to 1) clean the usb drive, 2) create a partition, 3) format the disk **NOT USING QUICK FORMAT**, and lastly I flash the usb drive with the newest version of Arch, 01-01-2020
3. I run through the install process, and each time I have tried something different, such as: installing just "plasma-desktop" and not "plasma" with "kde-applications", doing a **VERY** minimalist install with just pacstrapping base, base-devel, linux, and linux-lts, and I still cannot get a proper install

I have tried to follow other user posts on this issue (which have not worked), such as:

- Deleting any "*.lock" files (they were not there in the first place)
- Starting plasma not using SDDM

The log file, `~/etc/X11/Xorg.conf.d`, does not give any errors as far as I can tell for KDE or SDDM.

Once again, KDE Plasma freezes, after I log in from SDDM on Arch Linux, on the splash screen (what you see before the actual desktop)

Here is my list of commands I have used to install Arch:

[Arch Linux Install UEFI](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1izqk-aOUKu3l38EtDfJhE1gdfvbSFfbMgjEzaHw_IQo/edit?usp=sharing)

System Information:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz

RAM: 8.00 GB (7.87 useable)

Graphics:

- Integrated: Intel Graphics 630
- Dedicated: GTX 1050 (Mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by just not using the `xf86-video-intel` altogether, and only letting the kernel `modesetting` do the work.  Later, I installed `nvidia` and made it so I can switch between `nvidia` and `intel` graphics.

Answer (score 2):

As a starter, I would suggest

```
pacman -Rs xf86-video-intel
```

Often not recommended according to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics, then

```
pacman -S nvidia optimus-manager bbswitch
```

Reboot and if it didn't work, post

```
journalctl -b
```

You can also install `gnome` and use it to test whether it's a KDE-related issue